# updating partition Key, row movement not allowed

Tags: oracle, sql-update, partitioning, database-partitioning

i want to update a partition key. the partition is as below

```
PARTITION_NAME  LAST_ANALYZED   NUM_ROWS    BLOCKS  SAMPLE_SIZE HIGH_VALUE
PORTAL_SERVICE_1    12/8/2016   4133    174 4133    1
PORTAL_SERVICE_2    6/8/2016    4474    174 4474    2
PORTAL_SERVICE_3    10/8/2016   29602   2014    29602   3
PORTAL_SERVICE_OTHERS   24/5/2016   0   110     DEFAULT
```

this partition is applied on column Portal_Service_id. i want to update the value of  portal service id from 2 to 1.

when i try

```
update trans set PORTAL_SERVICE_ID = 1 where ID = 2054;
```

i get error: 
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-14402: updating partition key column would cause a partition change
14402. 00000 -  "updating partition key column would cause a partition change"

i am not allowed to use Enable Row Movement.

Can anybody please suggest any alternative to update the row.

can anybody shed some light if this can be used in the scenario:

```
UPDATE <table_name> PARTITION (<partition_name>)
SET <column_name> = <value>
WHERE <column_name> <condition> <value>;
```

Comment: Why do you have the `mysql` tag on an Oracle question.

Comment: Since you don't allow row movement, you need to delete the old row and insert a new row instead of updating.

Comment: do i use the regular delete? teh reason why i am askin is i cannot directly check this in the prod db, and test db doesn't hv partition... proj set up sucks !!!

Comment: Yes, regular delete. You'll need to save the old row contents in your application first, so you'll be able to insert it after.

Comment: @Barmar seems like delete is not an option either. I need to update somehow.. :(

Comment: It seems like you've backed yourself in a corner. Why would you configure partitioning based on a column that you want to update, but not allow movement? These are conflicting requirements, you can't satisfy both of them.

Answer (score 9):

to work around the error "ORA-14402: updating partition key column would cause a partition change" you can follow these steps

1) Check if for your table is enabled the row_movement

`SELECT owner,
       table_name,
       row_movement
FROM   dba_tables
WHERE  table_name in ('YOUR_TABLE');`

2) If is disabled you can enable movement with this script

```
alter table YOUR_TABLE enable row movement;
```

After that you can update the partition key column

Answer (score 1):

Enable row movement with this syntex , it will solve the error :

alter table <table_name> enable row movement

Answer (score 1):

Most of the other answers have pointed out one part of the solution, which is:

```
alter table <table_name> enable row movement
```

However, there's more to it than this.  Enabling row movement has some tradeoffs, which are pointed out here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_enable_row_movement.htm

In my case, this led me to double check why we were using a partition in the first place.  Ideally, a partition is for data that won't move around once it's in the partition.  If you're modifying the partition field (in my case a timestamp) then it may mean you shouldn't be using a partition.  If you're sure you want a partition on a mutable field, then at least make sure you periodically run:

```
"alter table shrink compact"
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question as the top Google result when searching for ORA-14402.  In my particular case I:

1. exported the rows as insert statements
2. updated the index key field and updated the ID field
3. inserted the rows as new rows.

You could then potentially delete the old rows if you have the need or leave them in the old partition.